# Error while trying to scaffold a model Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for MAC version 7.3.2 (build 12) and I'm trying to follow this tutorial from microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages-mac/model

I have followed every step but I'm getting this error: Version for package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` could not be resolve

My csproj file contain the following lines:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
```

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />

<DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.5.357" />

<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
```

Comment: At what step are you getting the error? Where is this error coming from?

Comment: Doing the scaffolding :  dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -h

Comment: Did you try running a dotnet restore from the command line in the same directory as the solution? VS Mac does not currently support restoring DotNetCliToolReferences.

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I've just followed the tutorial.

Comment: It looks like `dotnet restore` is included as one of the tutorial steps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mac does not have this package installed? Try to install this package.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools --version 2.0.4
```